# Delay on STM32F4 Discovery not working

Tags: arm, timer, stm32f4

I am trying to make a 10 seconds delay function using STM32F4 Discovery board. Unfortunately, it is not working and I don't know why. I have been two days on this problem. Can anyone help me please?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stm32f4xx_gpio.h>
#include <stm32f4xx_rcc.h>
#include <stm32f4xx_tim.h>

void configLED() {
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOD, ENABLE);
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_13;
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_OUT;
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_2MHz;
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);
}

void configTimerAndGpio() {
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOB, ENABLE);
    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM2, ENABLE);

    /*
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_3;
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_2MHz;
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_OD;
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, GPIO_Pin_3, GPIO_AF_TIM2);
    */

    //TIM_TimeBaseInitStruct.TIM_Period = 10000;
    TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef TIM_TimeBaseInitStruct;
    TIM_TimeBaseInitStruct.TIM_Period = 2000-1;
    TIM_TimeBaseInitStruct.TIM_Prescaler = 21000-1;
    TIM_TimeBaseInitStruct.TIM_ClockDivision = TIM_CKD_DIV1;
    TIM_TimeBaseInitStruct.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Down;
    TIM_TimeBaseInitStruct.TIM_RepetitionCounter=0;
    TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM2, &TIM_TimeBaseInitStruct);
    TIM_SetClockDivision(TIM_CKD_DIV1);
    TIM_PrescalerConfig(TIM2,Presacler,TIM_PSCReloadMode_Immediate);
    TIM_ITConfig(TIM_IT_UPDATE);
}

void delay() {
    TIM_Cmd(TIM2, ENABLE);
    while (TIM_GetFlagStatus(TIM2, TIM_FLAG_Update) != RESET) {
        TIM_ClearFlag(TIM2, TIM_FLAG_Update);
    }
    //while (TIM_GetCounter(TIM2) > 1) {
    //}
    TIM_Cmd(TIM2, DISABLE);
}

int main(void) {
    configTimerAndGpio();
    configLED();
    while (1) {
        GPIO_SetBits(GPIOD, GPIO_Pin_13);
        delay();
        GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOD, GPIO_Pin_13);
        delay();
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the symptoms? "Is not working" is not sufficient here. What is the expected behavior and the resulting behavior? What oscillator do you use and at which frequency?

Answer (score 1):

Actually ,i fixed that by using st's clock configuration tool to set the used clock to 84 MHZ then i did some calculation and modified the prescaler.

Answer (score 0):

On the link below you have tutorial on how to use Systick timer for delay.

Actually, library is written which do that for you.

http://stm32f4-discovery.com/2014/04/03-stm32f429-discovery-system-clock-and-pretty-precise-delays/

Comment: Please post a summary of the details from that link, otherwise the answer will become useless if the link dies.